# How disable stacking elements with Bourbon Neat

Tags: bourbon, neat

I am trying to retain a side-by-side layout at mobile widths with Bourbon Neat.

With Bootstrap, you can do:

```
<div class="outer row">
    <div class="inner col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="inner col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

What is the equivalent in Bourbon Neat?

Comment: I have answered my own question:

`.inner{
    @include span-columns(6);
    @include media($mobile) {
        @include span-columns(6);
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be side-by-side at all screen sizes you don't even need the

```
@include media($mobile)
```

just have

```
.inner{ @include span-columns(6);}
```

and it will be true at all screen sizes